# Expression denotes a `type', where a `variable', `value' or `method group' was expected UNITY3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () {
      float xP = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")*Time.deltaTime * 20; 
      transform.Translate (Vector3(xP,0,0));//error is here 
      transform.position.x = Mathf.Clamp (transform.position.x, -10, 10);
}
```

error : Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected`

Comment: Well what do you expect `Vector3(xP,0,0)` to do? I *suspect* you want `new Vector3(xP, 0, 0)` but we can't tell.

Comment: That's almost certainly it

Comment: adding "new" keyword is not working

Comment: @Hgp7 "not working" is not descriptive; please update the question or ask a new one with the details.

Comment: Like you can see here, use the new when creating new objects: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8472/help-with-error-expression-denotes-a-type-where-a.html

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `new` keyword that's necessary to call a constructor from C# code. Maybe the code was improperly translated from another language (e.g. the syntax there is valid in Python/Boo), or just written incorrectly.

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(xP, 0, 0));
```

You should consider writing it with [`Vector3.right`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-right.html) instead, to clarify the direction:

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.right * xP);
```